# updating data in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm fairly new to angular js, and not really sure how to google the terms i need.

I basically have a html page, bind to a controller. This page will load data from mysql.

in my controller, i have code like this when the page load:

```
thresholdNameSpace.controller("ThresholdController", ['$scope','$http', function ($scope, $http){
   $http.get('http://something.appspot.com/met').success(function(data){
   $scope.messages = data;
}]);
```

There is a functionality on the page that add new entry to the database. How do i update the controller so that after a new content is added to the database, it automatically gets displayed?

what keyword should i be looking for in angularjs term

Comment: Angular does this itself, it's one of its central points. Read the guide on data binding in Angular: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding

Answer (score 0):

well, just push the data to the server and send a response back... a brute-force approach would be to send back the entire data back, or just to append the current 'message' at the end of the messages object

```
thresholdNameSpace.controller("ThresholdController", ['$scope','$http', function ($scope, $http){

    // get data
    $http.get('http://something.appspot.com/met').success(function(data){
        // assuming messages is an array 
        $scope.messages = data; 
    });

    // create a function to push data up to the db, then update the view on success or failure appropriately
    $scope.updateDatabase = function(param1, param2, param3...){
        var parameters = {
            name: param1,
            date: param2,
            message: param3
        }
        $http.get('http://something.appspot.com/metUpdate', parameters).then(function(successResponse){
            console.log('successResponse', successResponse);
            if($scope.messages)
                $scope.messages.push({message: param3, person: param1, sent: param2}); // your object added to array
        }, function(failureResponse){
            console.log('failureResponse', failureResponse);
            // you can also push a error object which will be processed on the front end for proper display
            $scope.messages.push({error: failureReason.data.errorMessage});
        });

    }

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular automatically updates the html, you just have to update $scope.messages from the database.
For example, you can get the data every 30 seconds, with $interval.
Something like this :

```
var update = function() {
  $http.get('http://something.appspot.com/met').success(function(data){
    $scope.messages = data;
  }
}
$interval(update, 30000)
```

Don't forget to inject $interval in your controller.

Comment: wouldn't you say this is a bit brute-force and inefficient? Also, you need to be sure to clear the interval when leaving the page.

Comment: Of course @EliteOctagon, this is just an example, it needs to be adapted... I don't know how many "messages" are in the db, and how many users, and etc. It will be better to add only new messages, of course.